# Extract key value pairs from a tuple in Pig

Tags: unix, hadoop, apache-pig

I have a file with data as below:

> {"PASSWORD_MATCH_RATE":"0.00","PASSWORD_MATCH_COUNT":0,"PASSWORD_INVALIDATE_SUCCESS_COUNT":0,"NOTES":"dfh"}

In a pig script I want to dump the data as below:

> PASSWORD_MATCH_RATE,0.00
>
> PASSWORD_MATCH_COUNT,0
>
> PASSWORD_INVALIDATE_SUCCESS_COUNT,0
>
> NOTES,dfh

Can anyone provide any help on this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I have edited your post to markup the data using '>'.  Please edit the question and post the script you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

This will split your input. can you try this?

```
A = LOAD 'file' using TextLoader() as (line:chararray);
F = FOREACH A GENERATE REPLACE(line,'"','') as (line1:chararray);
F1 = FOREACH F GENERATE FLATTEN(TOKENIZE(line1)) AS (line2:chararray);
F2 = FOREACH F1 GENERATE REPLACE(line2,':',',');
```